# Safeguard an environment against tabular mode

Tags: tables, macros, environments, programming

The semantics of a given environment require that it is typeset inside a `minipage` if it is used inside a `tabular`. If I add the minipage declaration for a positive check for "internal" mode in the environment using `\ifinner`, it works: the minipage is added only if in `tabular` mode. (This can be seen in the output because the minipage does not expand over the full text width.) I have the following questions:

1. Why does the check for inner mode succeed when the `kframe` environment is closed? Is TeX in "internal" mode inside a `minipage` environment?
2. Is there a more reliable way to do this detection? Is the detection correct at all?

The `kframe` environment is used in code generated by knitr; it should work both inside and outside of a `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed}

\newenvironment{kframe}{%
  % The \ifinner check below is necessary
  \ifinner\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}\else\fi%
  \def\FrameCommand##1{\colorbox{yellow}{##1}}%
  \MakeFramed{}}{%
  \endMakeFramed%
  % Why does this \ifinner check work?
  \ifinner\end{minipage}\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{kframe}
  Any text long enough will do here.
  Any text long enough will do here.
  Any text long enough will do here.
\end{kframe}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\begin{kframe}
  Any text long enough will do here.
  Any text long enough will do here.
  Any text long enough will do here.
\end{kframe}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of MWE compilation]

Comment: `\ifinner` is true in internal vertical mode (so also inside a `minipage`), restricted horizontal mode (so also inside a `tabular`), in inline math mode and in any subformula in display math mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be very peculiar to *need* a `minipage` inside a tabular, there is virtually nothing about a tabular cell which isn't shared by `\mbox` (for `l` columns) or `\parbox` (for `p` columns.).

It looks to me like you need a minipage if in an `l` column or `\mbox` or other restricted horizontal mode so I think you want

```
  \ifinner\ifhmode  start minipage \fi\fi
```

This would start a minipage in a tabular `l` but not a tabular `p`. The code below contains the full implementation including egreg's remark on closing the `minipage` environment.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
  \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
  \ifinner\ifhmode%
    \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}%
  \fi\fi%
  \def\FrameCommand##1{\colorbox{yellow}{##1}}%
  \MakeFramed{}}{%
  \endMakeFramed%
  \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother
```

Comment: And `<start minipage>` should contain something like `\def\closekframe{\end{minipage}}`, while the normal definition would be `\def\closekframe{}`. At the end of the `kframe` environment `\closekframe` should be executed.

Comment: David: Thank you. The code works in my case. Do you mind if I update your answer with the fixed code, also containing egreg's remark?

Comment: sure edit away:-)